# I want to get data from SF using standard API call from iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, salesforce

I want to get JSON response from SF, by doing "standard API" call from iOS project.

1. want to send request and get all the account details.
2. want to send particular account id and get that json data.
3. Delete account by sending specific account id

I have "access token" and "Instance", currently i am forming URL something like this to get particular account details -

https://<"instance">/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Account/0010U000019HKD1Q<"access token">

I am not albe to build URL using "access token". Please guide me to build.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The access token never goes in a URL. You supply it as an HTTP header in your REST requests, as described in the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm):

> `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>`